# Where find Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll in VS Community 2017

Tags: visual-studio, build, process

I'm following this article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850441(v=vs.120).aspx#code_proj_references

I found Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client .dll, but not  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll

I use Visual Studio Community 2017.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer

Comment: It was a matter of framing the right question to get to this answer !